# Ресурсы по созданию сетевого клиента и сервера под Linux на С/С++

Tags: c, linux, сокет, c++, сервер

Посоветуйте, книжки, сайты, статьи на тему. Встала задача написать узкоспециализированный прокси сервер, а опыта в этом деле мало.

P.S. желательно на русском, но не обязательно.

Comment: В конечном счете я использовал epoll :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Быстро, просто и в целом достаточно.

На мой взгляд, из того, что требуется, только setsockopt(server,SOL_SOCKET,SO_REUSEADDR,...), ну, еще select() или poll() (часто они удобны) не рассмотрены.

http://kpnc.opennet.ru/sock.pdf

Comment: ссылка умерла...

Answer (score 0):

Д.Камер Сети TCP/IP. т1. Принципы, протоколы и структура.
т.3 Разработка приложений типа клиент-сервер для LINUX/POSIX